# Format a string wittout predetermined length in Java

Tags: java, string, printing, format

I need to print the table like in the picture:[the table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooE5z.png)

But as I have taks of different length (2nd, 3d, 4th and 5th column headers) I can't format strings wtih spaces

I tried using String.format("%10s", string) but this method doesn't accept length of the string through a variable (at least I haven't found any information)

Comment: Actually you have to use spaces to get the format. There is no way around it plain text.

Comment: Just make a variable out of that `10` in `String.format("%10s", string)`. It may look weird, but you can concat the template string just like any other: `String.format("%" + length + "s", string)`

Comment: Oh, thank you, I forgot I Can do that XD

Comment: String format just adds spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this. Create a method to create a format from a format.
Use a formatted string to create a final formatted string.  The first takes the lengths of the headers to create the final format.

```
 String h1 = "header 1";
 String h2 = "long header 2";
 String h3 = "other";
 String headerTemplate = "%%%ds|%%%ds|%%%ds%%n";
 // left justfied with negative lengths.
 String format = headerTemplate.formatted(-h1.length(), -h2.length(),
         -h3.length());
 System.out.printf(format,h1,h2,h3);
 System.out.printf(format, "A", "B", "C");
```

prints

```
header 1|long header 2|other
A       |B            |C
```